# 'LMSApp' object has no attribute 'show_records1'

Tags: python, sqlite, frontend, backend, kivy-language

In my .kv file I call my function show_records1 from the main python file named the same way and within the same window class. I have tried changing the app. to root. but that does not work and am confsued in trying to know where to go?

This is my .kv file

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:
    FourthWindow:
    FifthWindow:
    SixthAWindow:
    SixthBWindow:

<MainWindow>
    name: 'main'
    # Changing background color
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#9e9e9e')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    GridLayout
        cols: 2
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding:10
        spacing:10

        Label:
            text: "LMS Mobile GUI"
            # canvas.before:
            #     Color:
            #         rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#CCA7EA')
            #     Rectangle:
            #         size: self.size
            #         pos: self.pos
            # Text properties
            font_size: 34
            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#CCA7EA')
            bold:True
            italic:True
            outline_color: (0,0,0)
            outline_width: 1.5
        Button:
            text: "Task 1"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "first"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 2"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 3"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 4"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "fourth"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 5"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "fifth"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 6a"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "sixtha"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Task 6b"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "sixthb"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: utils.get_color_from_hex('#9e9e9e')
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding:10
        spacing:10

        Label:
            text: "Book Loan"
            font_size: 32

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Book Name: "

            TextInput:
                id: book_name1
                mutiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Show Records"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: **app.show_records1()
**
        Button:
            text: "Back To Main Menu"
            font_size: 32
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        Label:
            id: output1
            text: ''
```

This is my .py file that calls upon the .kv file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import sqlite3

# Define different screens

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class FirstWindow(Screen):
    def show_records1(self):
        sub_conn = sqlite3.connect('LMS.db')
        conn_cur = sub_conn.cursor()
        conn_cur.execute('''
        SELECT book_id FROM Book
        WHERE title = :book_name;
        ''',

        {
            'book_name': self.root.ids.book_name1.text
            }



        )
        output_records = conn_cur.fetchall()
        for recors in output_records:
            self.root.ids.output1.text = f'Book ID #: {output_records}'


        sub_conn.commit()
        sub_conn.close()


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records2(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records3(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class FourthWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records4(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class FifthWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records5(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class SixthAWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records6a(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class SixthBWindow(Screen):
    # def show_records6b(self):
    #     conn
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('multi.kv')

class LMSApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LMSApp().run()
```

I've tried changing the variable name of show_records1 to others, tried making the output different within the function tried changing the kv file, was worried that the function was looking at it globally but that didn't work either.